# Displaying data from one form to a label in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently having problem in displaying my transferred `String` data from the my 1st form to the second one. I tried putting a button in my 2nd form to check if the data is transferred, and I confirmed that the data was transferred by using `MessageBox.Show()` command. But when I try to assign it to my `Label` the `Label` text does not change. Here is my Sample Code:

First Form: Data transfer is being triggered by clicking a cell in my `dataGridView`

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupSummary f = new PopupSummary();
        f.searchText = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        this.Hide();
        f.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
```

Second Form:

```
     public string searchText = "";
private void PopupSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = searchText;
        }
```

Note:

`label1` is inside a tableLayoutPanel.

My main problem is that the label.Text does not change the text of my current label even if the data was successfully transferred. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're assigning your new text to `searchText`, *not* to `label1.Text`.  The only time you assign anything to `label1.Text` is on form load, in `PopupSummary_Load`, when you set it to the value of `searchText`.  Simply changing the value of `searchText` *after* that won't cause the label text to be updated.

You can do any number of things now that you know what is going on, but here is a simple one:

```
f.label1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: `f.label1.Text` causes an error saying inaccessible due to its protection level. how can I change its protection level?

Comment: What is its current protection level?  `private` I'm guessing.  Change it to `friend` or `public` or something other than `private`?

Comment: nevermind that, I overlooked at the `Modifiers` in the properties

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but It still doesn't work, I appreciate the additional knowledge. Is there any restriction in changing a `tableLayoutPanel`'s content?

Comment: the `label1.Text` is still not changing its text value, I tried putting a button in my 2nd form to change the `label1.Text` to a random text but nothing is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening then.  I'm assuming you've set break points and debugged it and all that?

Comment: after multiple debugging and trying other things, I ended up creating a new form. It seems that the problem is coming from the form itself so I just recreated it, and your solution works. Thank YOu.